# Prolog intersection list of lists

Tags: list, matrix, prolog, intersection

I want to create an intersection of lists of lists in prolog. (Matrix, with lists as cells)

I have to handle only the case, when number of rows and columns are the same (Rectangular). The lists are ordered, and does not contain any duplicate elements (they are ord_sets).

How could I do that?

Example: (3 rows, 3 columns)

```
A:
[[[1,2],[3,2,1],[3,4,5]],
[[1,2],[3,2,1],[3,4,5]],
[[1,2],[3,2,1],[3,4,5]]]
B:
[[[1],[3,2,1],[3,4,5]],
[[1,2],[2,1],[3,4]],
[[1,2],[3,2,1],[3,9,10,4,5]]]
C:
[[[1],[3,2,1],[3,4,5]],
[[1,2],[2,1],[3,4]],
[[1,2],[3,2,1],[3,4,5]]]
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You do that by really thinking very hard about the problem, putting some effort into it, and eventually try to write one or more predicates and debug these.

Comment: I've had play around with maplist, ord_intersection, and forall, but could not combine them in a way, that it do what I want. I am pretty new in prolog.

Comment: Perhaps you better first look for a way to obtain the intersection of two simple lists. Next you can look to find the intersection of two rows and finally for two matrices.

Comment: With two helper predicates, we can do this with a one-liner.

Comment: I am stuck at the intersection of two rows.
This is what I've tried, but doesn't working:

ir([], [], _).
ir([H|T], [H1|T1], Out) :- ord_intersection(H, H1, O), append(Out, O, O2), ir(T, T1, O2), Out = O2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Prolog interpreters already have a predicate to calculate the intersection between two lists: [**`intersection/3`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=intersection/3). For example:

```
?- intersection([3,2,1], [3,9,10,4,5], R).
R = [3].
```

We can use `maplist/3` to process an entire row of such lists:

```
?- maplist(intersection, [[1,2],[3,2,1],[3,4,5]], [[1],[3,2,1],[3,4,5]], C).
C = [[1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 4, 5]].
```

And by using another `maplist/3` we process the matrices:

```
?- maplist(maplist(intersection),[[[1,2],[3,2,1],[3,4,5]], [[1,2],[3,2,1],[3,4,5]], [[1,2],[3,2,1],[3,4,5]]], [[[1],[3,2,1],[3,4,5]],[[1,2],[2,1],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,2,1],[3,9,10,4,5]]], C).
C = [[[1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 4, 5]], [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 2, 1], [3, 4, 5]]].
```

So we can do the processing with:

```
intersect_matrix(A, B, C) :-
    maplist(maplist(intersection), A, B, C).
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer was very helpful for me.